# MySQL - Efficient search with partial word match and relevancy score (FULLTEXT)

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

How can I do a MySQL search which will match partial words but also provide accurate relevancy sorting?

```
SELECT name, MATCH(name) AGAINST ('math*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM subjects
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('math*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The problem with boolean mode is the relevancy always returns 1, so the sorting of results isn't very good. For example, if I put a limit of 5 on the search results the ones returned don't seem to be the most relevant sometimes.

If I search in natural language mode, my understanding is that the relevancy score is useful but I can't match partial words.

Is there  a way to perform a query which fulfils all of these criteria:

- Can match partial words
- Results are returned with accurate relevancy
- Is efficient

The best I've got so far is:

```
SELECT name
FROM subjects
WHERE name LIKE 'mat%'
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM subjects
WHERE name LIKE '%mat%' AND name NOT LIKE 'mat%'
```

But I would prefer not to be using `LIKE`.

Comment: One option is to look for alternative to mysql`s FULLTEXT such as sphinx. http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/02/07/use-sphinx-with-mysql/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I obtained a good solution in this (somewhat) duplicate question a year later:

[MySQL - How to get search results with accurate relevance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711370/mysql-how-to-get-search-results-with-accurate-relevance)

Answer (score 17):

The new InnoDB full-text search feature in MySQL 5.6 helps in this case.
I use the following query:

```
SELECT MATCH(column) AGAINST('(word1* word2*) ("word1 word1")' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score, id, column 
FROM table
having score>0
ORDER BY score 
DESC limit 10;
```

where `( )` groups words into a subexpression. The first group has `like word%` meaning; the second looks for exact phrase. The score is returned as float.

Comment: Why are you searching for 2 groups? Does the match for both groups generate higher score? (it seems not...)

Comment: Adding `*` after my search term did it for me.