# Tweaking MySQL's ngram fulltext index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If I index the terms `Maya Angelou` and `May Angelou` (using MySQL's ngram fulltext index parser) and then search for the term `may`, the two items get the exact same score. Is there a way to optimize it so that `May Angelou` comes up first?

See:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(200)
);

ALTER TABLE test ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `test_fulltext_index`(title) WITH PARSER ngram;

insert into test(title) values('Maya Angelou');
insert into test(title) values('May Angelou');


SELECT title, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('may') as SCORE FROM test WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('may');
```

This results in:

```
+--------------+----------------------------+
| title        | SCORE                      |
+--------------+----------------------------+
| Maya Angelou | 0.000000003771856604828372 |
| May Angelou  | 0.000000003771856604828372 |
+--------------+----------------------------+
```

Of course, using a normal `FULLTEXT` index (without the `ngram` parser) gives the following:

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| title       | SCORE              |
+-------------+--------------------+
| May Angelou | 0.0906190574169159 |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

I thought of having two indexes: one a normal `FULLTEXT` index and the other one using `WITH PARSER ngram` and then combining the results, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

How could this be done?

Comment: Have you tried fulltext search with boolean mode?

Comment: Yes, a boolean mode search results in the same score as well: `SELECT title, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('may*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as SCORE FROM test WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('may*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` results in `Maya Angelou | 0.000000001885928302414186` and `May Angelou  | 0.000000001885928302414186`

Comment: Had the same problem, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711370/mysql-how-to-get-search-results-with-accurate-relevance/49004865#answer-49004865